# How to cast from Double to GridLength? C#

Tags: c#, xaml, stackpanel

I'm trying to get the value of a GridRow[0] and  its parent (Stackpanel), then I'm substracting the value of GridRow[0] of Stackpanel value. 
The last step for  me is assign the result to GridRow[1].

```
gridLengthVariable  = othergridLengthVariable - doubleVariable;
```

In this case I can't do a explicit conversion from Double to GridLength

```
gridLengthVariable.Value
```

Is a readable only property so I can't assign here.

I need one way to cast double to gridLength although I'm open minded to make deeper changes in my code if this bring me the same solution.

XAML changes can't be done.

EDIT:

I will show what I'm trying to do:

It's a dynamic change of a XAML created gridRow.

```
     gridProfile.RowDefinitions[1].Height =  
     stackPanelProfile.Height -  gridProfile.RowDefinitions[0].Height;
```

Here I can't apply operator "**-**"

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know C#, but I guess using the constructor should work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A Gridlength can be Auto, Pixel or Star. Simply using the value without checking which type it is might not be the smartest plan.

Comment: What's your end-goal here? What are you trying to do with this manually calculated gridlength? Sounds like you might want to create a custom panel instead.

Comment: I expandend my post... maybe there is not a supported way to do what I want without change XAML structure. Thanks  for your time.

Answer (score 6):

[`GridLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx) is a struct. It is much more than a single double value. It can be `Auto` for example too.

You can make a new `GridLength` and provide the actual value through the constructor:

```
gridLengthVariable = new GridLength(othergridLengthVariable - doubleVariable);
```

Comment: Maybe I was doing something wrong when I tested your code, but at the end is the same problem that I have...The problem is still the same. I know that is not possible convert GridLength to double  on the way I posted  but I'm looking for an alternative solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like this? `gridProfile.RowDefinitions[1].Height =  new GridLength(stackPanelProfile.Height.Value -  gridProfile.RowDefinitions[0].Height.Value);`. It is hard to get it right when you don't know the exact types. (And I didn't see your edit btw)

Comment: Now, I am getting an unexpected NaN in      
        gridProfile.RowDefinitions[0].Height.Value, I will check again my code, and then I will make deep changes on it. Thanks for your help.